# Java scanner class

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a small search engine that uses the Java Scanner class to read a file, matching user queries to the queried keyword in the file.

However i have a problem, i need to rank these keywords, if i search for "computer" and the file being searched contains 4 instances of "computer they will all be displayed within one line, because they are the same.

However if it returns " the computer shop" then this should be ranked lower, than just "computer because i did not search for "the computer shop"

I hope you understand, ho can i do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you your problem is in search engine logic. In this case class Scanner is irrelevant. It is just a convenient utility to read data from stream.

Concerning to search engine please define better your input and required output. Generally you should search for better matching of your query with target text. What does it mean? It is very complicated. Probably longer char sequence, probably more matching words etc. People wrote hundreds of PhDs about this and created thousands of companies (did you hear about Google? :)).

So, unless it is homework try to use tools like Solr or Lucine. Otherwise think about strategies I mentioned above.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be to create an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).  Instead of going from a file to the words in the file, you do the opposite.

A simple implementation in Java might just be done using `Map<String,List<File>>`, where the string is the word and the list of files represents the files that contain that.